# Do not show the "If you found this helpful, please upvote" message to experienced users

Tags: feature-request

Experienced users should not be shown the top-of-screen pop-down message reminding them to upvote a question if they find it helpful.

This is particularly annoying when that reminder comes right after closing out the login pop-down message after arriving at a random stackexchange site from Google.

This network should not slow down and annoy experienced users with excessive messages. This message, in particular, is only useful to new users.